# Why is the url function used more often in Django 1.5 documentation?

Tags: django

I'm working with some older Django code and the `url` function is not used anywhere, similar to the examples in [the Django 1.4 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^articles/2003/$', 'news.views.special_case_2003'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'),
)
```

but I notice in [the Django 1.5 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/) the `url` function is used frequently:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', 'news.views.special_case_2003'),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'),
)
```

Why is this?  Is it a matter of convention, or is there a technical reason to use the `url` function?  Which practice should I follow in the future, and how should I maintain my legacy code without `url` calls?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but just tried to remove `url` from a Django 1.5 app and it threw an error. So it's probable not just a convention and it must be necessary

Comment: @romainberger The Django 1.5 tutorial doesn't use it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/overview/, and the documentation mentions tuples are fine. Your error must lie elsewhere, or the tutorial is out-of-date.

Comment: The technical reason is that you can use named parameters in a function, which is convenient when most of the members of the tuple are optional. My guess is `url()` just adds sane default values for the optional elements and returns a tuple. (Seeing as you have a Django environment set up, you can easily try and see what calling `url()` directly in a REPL does.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#url)

> url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None, prefix='')
>
> You can use the url() function, instead of a tuple, as an argument to patterns(). This is convenient if you want to specify a name without the optional extra arguments dictionary. For example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index/$', index_view, name="main-view"),
    ...
)
```

And you use them for reverse URL matching (again, the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#id2))

You could convert the first example as:

```
url(r'^articles/2003/$', special_case_2003, name="special_case_2003"),
```

and call it in your template

```
{% url special_case_2003 %}
```

Yeah, maybe the two examples you posted are a bit too fuzzy about this

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OP's question.

Comment: Also, reversing URLs should work just fine without the use of `url()`.  I'd bet dollars to donuts that function just returns a tuple again.

Comment: Yes it does: reverse URL matching is a common practice in django. That's why the 1.5 docs use it as often as possible. Because its a best practice.

Comment: You're missing the point. The OP isn't asking "what does `url()` do?", or "what do I need `url()` for?". He's asking what the difference between using `url()` and passing plain tuples to `patterns()` is, which one is better. whether one is deprecated, etc. And I submit that there is no difference (besides the optional parameter support), and most certainly no difference when it comes to support for reverse URL resolution - that works no matter how you set up your URLconf.